# How can I parse a string of an array into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, request.querystring

```
{scenarios: "[{purchasePrice:11,downPayment:1,term:30,rate:1}]"}
```

That's my object. I want to turn the value of scenarios into the array its trying to be from the string it is.

Is there a quick tool so I don't have to hack it together from .splits?

Comment: `eval()` can be used

Comment: How is that string created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ***if*** the string comes from a trusted source, you can use `eval`, which will evaluate the string as JavaScript code:

```
var scenarios = eval(theObject.scenarios);
```

Since `eval` allows running any arbitrary code, don't use it on strings from untrusted sources. Additionally, it tends to make it difficult or impossible for the JavaScript engine to optimize the code it's in, so isolate your use of it in a function so the impact is kept to a minimum.

Comment: Even though it's not valid JSON, it's still probably safer to do `JSON.parse(obj.scenarios);` right?

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, no, because that will just fail with an error. ***If*** it were valid JSON, *then* yes, it would be much better to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see...

Comment: Unfortunately it is a querystring param.

Is there another way to store an array of objects safely in the QS?

Comment: @AronGreenspan Why not use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @AronGreenspan: As LGSon said: Use JSON. So for instance, your string would be `[{"purchasePrice":11,"downPayment":1,"term":30,"rate":1}]`, which would look like `%5B%7B%22purchasePrice%22%3A11%2C%22downPayment%22%3A1%2C%22term%22%3A30%2C%22rate%22%3A1%7D%5D` when URI-encoded, e.g. `http://example.com/foo?scenarios=%5B%7B%22purchasePrice%22%3A11%2C%22downPayment%22%3A1%2C%22term%22%3A30%2C%22rate%22%3A1%7D%5D`. Then you just `JSON.parse` it.